# How to access tiles in Tilecache using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapserver, tilecache

I've Mapserver set up with a mapfile that points to a tileindex. In QGIS I can call the mapfile and view the rasters dynamically. I've got access to tilecache and I've seeded the same mapfile/rasters that I view in QGIS. My question is, what do I need to do to get QGIS to access the tilecache as opposed the dynamic rasters?

I'm guessing that I need to do either something to my mapfile to get it to point to the seeded rasters as opposed to the dynamic rasters or repoint the WMS in QGIS